# ANDROID - Error opening emulator version 4.0

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3

When I open the emulator with the 4.0 version it gives the following error:

> com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Not a directory

Has anyone had this error and know how to tb?

Comment: U'll find this post useful. [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354480/com-android-ddmlib-syncexception-too-many-open-files