# How to stop an activity in android using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I think this is a basic question. Is there any option to stop an activity by using intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:5554"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This is my code. I would like to stop this activity (That means, i want to drop this call) if the user is busy or something. What can I do for that? I tried this:

```
if (condition) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:5554"));
    startActivity(intent);
}else {
    this.finish();
}
```

But of no use. Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: Seems like it would be a security violation if one application could kill another one.

Comment: Unless of course the target application published this capability via an Intent.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had this problem a few days ago, and I'm happy to tell you I've found a way around this.

First of all, to the activity you want to stop add this in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

I'm going to use a CheckBox example. When it's checked the activity is started and when unchecked will kill the activity.

Example Activity A is calling Activity B and then killing it using an intent.

Code to be put in A:

```
checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            if (enable.isChecked()) {
                intent.putExtra("keep", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                intent.putExtra("keep", false);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Code to be put into B:

```
boolean keep;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.B);
    intent = this.getIntent();
    boolean keep = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("keep");
    if(keep==true)
    {
        //execute your code here

    }
 }
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    keep = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("keep");
    if(keep==false)
    {
        B.this.finish();
    }
}
```

Explanation : What this basically does is, when the checkbox is checked it calls the activity and passes a boolean value, if it's true the activity is kept alive and is brought to the foreground. Now, if you don't pass the flag `singleTop` then many instances of this activity will be created. `singleTop` makes sure only the same instance is called. Now, when the checkbox is unchecked a new value for keep is passed which is verified in B. If unchecked, the Activity A will be passing false, and hence B terminates itself from within the `onNewIntent()` function.

P.S - You can close Activity B from another Activity too. Just use 
If the other activity is C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("keep", false);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Torcellite!! This may help me alot.

Comment: @Tony Any time, do vote it up for others to view it in case they run into this :)

Comment: @Tony Also, experiment with the code in B a little, it may not work very well unless since I don't know what exactly you want.

Comment: Nop!! I got the idea from first one itself(Code A). Actually I want to make a call by using an intent and have to cut the call if the user is busy with some another call. That's why I used StartActivity(Intent); but has no idea of how to stop it. I searched a lot for a method like stopActivity. But didn't found yet.

Comment: There is no `stopActivity`. This is the way I've figured out to kill one activity from another activity.

Comment: @ Torcellite I have not much reputation to vote it up. But sure I will guide them. Thank You!!

Comment: I believe onNewIntent() does not get called if Activity B was not already open. Furthermore, skipping initialization in onCreate() will NOT stop the activity from launching. **Therefore, in onCreate(), must have: `if(keep==false){ finish(); }`**

Comment: @Jodes If activity B was not already open, the Dev wouldn't want to close it, would he?

Comment: But the intent will launch activity B whether or not keep==false! So while it might not have been open, the intent to close will open it, so it then needs to be closed. (Unless I'm being really stupid here)

Comment: @Jodes - Unless the checkbox has been checked, there's no way the activity would've started. However, your case is valid. If the OP isn't using a checkbox and is using a button, then your case is valid.

Comment: @Jodes - Na, you thought of a specific case that I didn't. Kudos :)

Comment: @KarthikBalakrishnan I did an upvote because it took me on the right track. However, I do not need the mentioned manifest entry but use `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` and handle extra boolean `keep` in `onStart()` without using `onNewIntent()`. Then I use `startActivity(intent)` with intent having these flags set: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn  off the background data of play store and play services for not entering the play store .it will simply say,
" COULD NOT BE LOADED  "
 Thats the only way i found to stop intent

Comment: @Sree Where's the link here?

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked for me:
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <activity android:name=".ui.activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.STOP_SERVICE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Intent:

```
Intent stopBackgroundServiceIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
// Remove the activity when finish is called
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```