# Option menu option not directing to another activity

Tags: android, optionmenu

I want to navigate to another `Activity` when click on the option menu item 'settings' from the menu bar. Nothing actual happens.I have checked similar issues posted here, but i can understand why this is not working for option menu. 
see the code below:

[Can't go to a new activity from selected option from option menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182856/cant-go-to-a-new-activity-from-selected-option-from-option-menu)

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/mySettings"

    android:title="@string/action_settings" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/logout"

    android:title="log out" />
```

code:

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.app_bar_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    public void openConfigure(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Configure.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.mySettings:
                openConfigure();

                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }


        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onOptionsItemSelected` instead of `onContextItemSelected` cause you are using `OptionMenu` not `ContextMenu`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.mySettings:
            openConfigure();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: i have change it to onOptionsItemSelected , but still not opening the other Activity.

Comment: What happen when you click on menu item ? Also Check Manifest entry for `Configure` Activity it its not there ?

Comment: when i click no error shows, and is not opening the Configure Activity. the Manifest entry is also there:<activity android:name=".Configure" />

Comment: your solutions works. however, it opens a different Activity.

Comment: It will open the Activity you stated inside `Intent` in this case `Configure` .. You probably messed up with code or Layout .

Answer (score 0):

to select an options menu item, you have to override onOptionItemSelected() :
try below code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.mySettings:
            openConfigure();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```