# Stop a running app you just started

Tags: android, android-service

have some trouble stopping an app that I start with startActivity. Here is how I start it:

```
Intent theApp = new Intent();
theApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(thePackageName);
                           theApp.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                           theApp.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                           getApplicationContext().startActivity(theApp);
```

after it has ran for awhile, im trying to stop it like this:

```
                               if(stopService(theApp))
                                   Log.d(TAG,"Stopped app successfully!");
                               else
                                   Log.d(TAG,"Failed to stop the app!");
```

Any ideas why this isnt working? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Call finish(); This will kill it.

Comment: can You show us the real complete code?

Comment: You are trying to kill an external application that you started.. Right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are starting an activity. and you are trying to stop a service, which will not work.
If you want to stop the whole application. you can use System.exit().

Comment: I dont want to stop my application, I want to stop the application that I just started with startActivity()

Comment: Can I make an uninstall call and that stop it and uninstall the app? or would it just fail?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this isn't working is that your are trying to stop an Activity using a method that is designed to stop a Service.

You could try to have a static reference to the newly created activity and then call finish() when you want it ended.

Or you could try this method: [How to stop an activity in android using intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411477/how-to-stop-an-activity-in-android-using-intent)

Answer (score 0):

Search for killBackgroundProcess(pid)  or Kill process by packegename .

Comment: Just tried using this and it didnt work. Any ideas? I'm passing the packagename as the parameter