# How to close dialog themed Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog, android-theme, activity-finish

I have a dialog themed activity that contains only a ProgressBar with a single TextView. The code of that activity looks like this:

```
public class ProgressDialog extends Activity{

TextView msg;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);

    msg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progressMsg);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String msgString = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
    msg.setText(msgString);

}

}
```

This represents a ProgressBar Dialog that I will use for my Project so that I have a same look and easy costumizable Dialog on all versions of Android.

The problem is how can I finish this activity from an `AsyncTask onPostExecute()` method if I start it in the `onPreExecute()` method as a normal activity. The AsyncTask is called in another Activity. I tried different things but have not managed to succeed. I tried:

- Simulate a back press button
- Using fragmentManager and activityManager
- Implementing a public method in the Activity that calls the finish() method for an activity

Please help! If you need some additional code let me know!

Best regards!

Comment: does finish() dont work for you in onpostexecute of asynctask?

Comment: No. Because I need an instance of the running Dialog Themed Activity to do that. And that is the main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a method along these lines in the calling activity and call it to remove the dialog:

```
private void removeDialog() {
    Intent removeDialogIntent = new Intent(this, ProgressDialogActivity.class).setAction(ACTION_CLOSE_DIALOG);
    startActivity(removeDialogIntent);
}
```

And in the progressDialogActivity make sure to handle it:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (ACTION_CLOSE_DIALOG.equals(intent.getAction())){
        finish();
    }
}
```

You can stop the activity from a service or any other context, just add the relevant flags to the intent.

Having said that, personally I would use DialogFramgent and avoid all this mess, why do you need a dialog activity...?

Comment: Just to let all know. This is the right way but you have to set the launchMode to SingleTop of the activity in the manifest. Otherwise it will reopen a dialog with the new intent. For more detail look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14411650/1425032

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an AsyncTask, why don't you start the `ProgressDialog` in the AsyncTask `onPreExecute` ?

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public RecordAndAlignTask(MyMainActivity activity) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Doing something, please wait.");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, if you want to show it in this Activity, maybe you should just use

```
progressBar.show();
```

and then execute the dismiss when you are done loading.

```
if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

[See tutorial](http://briandolhansky.com/blog/2013/7/11/snippets-android-async-progress).

Comment: Sorry this is with a default ProgressDialog I cant use the default dialog.  Thank you anyways.