# Debugging Android native application using ndk-gdb

Tags: android, native-code, android-debug, ndk-gdb

I am trying to debug my android application having some native(c++) code using ndk-gdb in eclipse.It seems that by gdb server starts successfully from command line and is taking commands.
But in eclipse it is showing this error :
Error while obtaining file from device
com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Writing local file failed

Any one help me please.

Comment: I encounter the same problem. Did you eventually found a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot debug android native code built on android library on eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887892/cannot-debug-android-native-code-built-on-android-library-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the framework for debugging requires an `obj/local/armeabi` folder.

If you open the launch file for native debugging, `.metadata/.plugins/org.ecipse.debug.core/.launches/*.launch`, you'll see a reference in that xml file:

`<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.cdt.launch.PROGRAM_NAME" value="/projectroot/obj/local/armeabi/app_process"/>`

Once I created this folder on disk this error subsided, and I was able to debug.  There may be a more correct way to fix this, but I simply decided it was simple enough to create this folder.

Comment: Nice, thanks. In my case I had to add an `obj/local/armeabi-v7a` folder.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354480/com-android-ddmlib-syncexception-too-many-open-files) seems similar. Try some of the answers shown and see if they help.